# corank of Jacobian and local Krull dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am confused about the relationship between smoothness and local Krull dimension.

Let $X = \mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/(f_1,\cdots,f_k)$ and $x \in X$ be a point such that the Jacobian $\left( \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} (x) \right) \in M_{n \times (n-k)}(\kappa(x))$ has rank $n-k$. (i.e. $X$ is smooth at $x$). Then I want to show that the local Krull dimension of $X$ at $x$ is $n-k$. Here local Krull dimension is defined by $\dim_x X = \inf_{x \in U,U \text{ open}} \dim U$.

I believe that this statement should be true, but I find no proof in the literatures. I guess that there should be some relationships between local Krull dimension and rank of $\Omega_{X/k}$ at $x$ to deduce this fact?

Comment: What do you mean, you "find no proof in the literature"? This is trivial from a combination of algebraic results mentioned in Hartshorne chapter I, for instance.

Comment: @KReiser I don't think so. Here $k$ is an arbitrary field and $x$ need not to be a closed point.